# ActiveAdmin: how to make a simple button with method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In activeAdmin, I am trying to edit the table form to add a button on each element which will simply change an attribute of the record.

I found a way to do it via

```
a link_to ("Good"), review_state_admin_bidule_path(bidule, :state =>"good"), :method => :put

member_action :review_state, :method => :put do
    Bidule.find(params[:id]).update_column(:review_state, params[:state])
    redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

But the problem is that a member_action always seems to be linked to an url, therefore reload the whole table.
Is there a way to avoid this final "redirect_to" ?

Comment: i think it's possible to inject your own JavaScript into ActiveAdmin. using JS you should be able to send this request via AJAX and have the user stay on the same page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer to refresh the page than to go out of activeadmin scope

Comment: what do you mean by "go out of the activeadmin scope"?

Comment: not using active record for modifying my objects

Comment: sorry, i don't get that. why would you not use active record for that?

Comment: "using JS you should be able to send this request via AJAX" which request are you talking about ? not the update_column ?